# Fragmented AsyncTask WebView causing problems

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-asynctask

I'm following

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/

to get an idea as to how to use AsyncTask for my project, all goes well and all but there's just one minor issue; best practice for Android is to use fragments to handle all the GUI...

Using fragments wasn't so hard last time I tried doing it, so I thought I could just jump straight into it and follow the tutorial best I could...

Long story short, the program crashes every time I hit the button to load the WebView

Here's my Fragment:

```
package com.wausoft.app;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    protected ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    protected View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_dummy:
                    dummyFunc(view);
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_load:
                    readWebpage();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        buttons.add((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_load));
        buttons.add((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_dummy));

        for(Button btn : buttons) btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

        return view;
    }

    public void dummyFunc(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void readWebpage() {
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/");
        LoadWebpageAsync task = new LoadWebpageAsync();
        task.execute(url);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.v("DEBUG: ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class LoadWebpageAsync extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try {
            WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.web_view);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // program crashes here
            webView.loadUrl(urls[0].toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("DEBUG: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        }
    }
}
```

And for the record; this is the error message I get:

```
01-10 17:09:52.544  23959-24282/? V/DEBUG:﹕ java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'AsyncTask #1'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 1) {41e2e8d8} called on null, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 1) {41e2e8d8})
```

So can any of you tell me how to fix this? Without getting rid of the AsyncTask or the Fragment that is...

From the responses I got **I conclude this**: *Find a better tutorial...* Thanks guys!

Comment: get rid of asynctask. webview is a view why do you want that in a background thread. makes no sense

Comment: @Raghunandan the whole point of this was to use AsyncTask, if I get rid of it it eliminates the whole purpose of the program

Comment: what you are doing is wrong. you should use asynctask if you are doing something does no involve updating ui like a network operation

Comment: That is an awful tutorial...

Comment: @EmbattledSwag got a better one for me to try out instead?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee Here's a better one. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html As other people have mentioned, you should never do UI stuff in `doInbackground` (similar to how you shouldn't do network tasks on the main thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are loading a url in webview in `doInbackground`. You should do on the ui thread.

You would use asynctask while doing some network related operation like getting data from server.

Pls move you webview code to `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`

Also there is no need for `ArrayList<Button>`. You just have 2 buttons

```
Button b1,b2; 
WebView wb;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        b1= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_load);
        b2=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_dummy);

        b1.setOnClickListener(listener);
        b2.setOnClickListener(listener);

        wb= (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/"); 

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: but doesn't that decrease the responsiveness of the program by having it wait for the webview to finish loading?

Comment: @ElectricCoffee nope untill you are doing some heavy task that needs to run on background thread which is not the case with loading a url in webview

Comment: @ElectricCoffee for 2 buttons you have a arraylist of buttons!. not required

Comment: @ElectricCoffee refer docs that is best tutorial and check samples in the sdk

Comment: I know I don't strictly need the arraylist, but I add it anyway in case I add more buttons... it saves a lot of repeated code

Answer (score 0):

View objects cannot be loaded in an background thread, they must be accessed and modified in the UI thread.

The WebVIEW is a view object. Stop calling it in the AsyncTask's "doinBACKGROUND" thread